# Getting debug messages when running Apache velocity template

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, velocity

I'm running Apache velocity template engine (2 latest)
I keep getting below debug messages from SLF4J
This obstructs the user from viewing important messages, is there a way to suppress these messages?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user1/Package/installer/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user1/Package/installer/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message warns you about **multiple SLF4J** classes,

You have 2 slf4j jars `slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar` and `slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar` which both have the same class (StaticLoggerBinder),

Remove one of the jars from dependencies and the debug message will disappear.